# How to navigate one step to another steps programmatically in ngx-admin nebular stepper?

Tags: angular, nebular, ngx-admin

I am using nebular `ngx-admin` template. I am facing some issues in nebular stepper. I have used four steps in one component.

I used Nebular API's methods in component file:

```js
@ViewChild("stepper") stepper: NbStepperComponent;

this.stepper.next();
this.stepper.previous();
this.stepper.reset();
```

The `next()` is navigate to next steps. 
The `previous()` is navigate to previous steps.
The `reset()` is navigate to first step and reset all form data.

How can I navigate from 4th step to 2nd step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this way,

In HTML file

```
 <nb-stepper #stepper [(selectedIndex)]="stepperIndex">

    <nb-step [stepControl]="serviceForm" label="Select Package">

    <button nbButton 
    (click)="backToSelectPackage()">ADD</button>

    </nb-step> 

 </nb-stepper>
```

In Component.ts file

```
stepperIndex: number = 0; // here 0 is initial index

backToSelectPackage() {
  this.stepperIndex = 0; // here 0 is navigate index
}
```

Note:

If used **[(selectedIndex)]** , We can't use next(), Previous() and nbStepperNext, nbStepperPrevious.

Comment: Note that `selectedIndex` will also overrides the behavior of `nbStepperPrevious` and `nbStepperNext` buttons.

Answer (score -2):

```
this.stepper.goto(2);
```

it will navigate to second step...

Comment: there is no method goto in nbstepper

Comment: please update the ngx-stepper lib   RUN : "npm update ngx-stepper"

Comment: I used nb stepper. why i update ngx-stepper

Comment: use this.stepper.selectedIndex=2